# Azure Function ImportError while importing test module / ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, azure-functions, pytest, python-unittest

I'm writing some tests for a Python Azure function and I'm getting an import error in the test module.

> ImportError while importing test module...

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named...

The error only occurs when the test module is located in the /tests directory. If I drop in to the root directory it runs fine.

Directory Structure:

```
Project
/.venv
/function/Orchestrator/__init__.py
/function/ActivityA/__init__.py
/function/ActivityB/__init__.py
/function/tests/test_activities.py
```

test_activities.py

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
import ActivityA
```

Error:

```
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\...\function\tests\test_activities.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
function\tests\test_activities.py:4: in <module>
    import A_WorkItemIds
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ActivityA'
```

I've tried using relative paths to import the ActivityA module but get different errors.

Can someone tell me why the test module does not work from the /tests directory?

Is there an approach to get this to work?

I've reviewed similar questions but none of them have given me an answer.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `python -m pytest` to run the tests? Do you run it from the root directory?

Comment: Yes I am using that statement to run the tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve this with a couple of amendments.

In the tests module (test_activities.py), I changed the ActivityA import to:

```
from function import ActivityA
```

When running the test I used:

```
python -m pytest function/tests
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are missing an `__init__.py` in your tests folder. I can not reproduce your error using a structure replicating your question. I set up a directory with the following structure:

```
functions/
├── ActivityA
│   └── __init__.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_foo.py
```

The contents of `test_foo.py` is the following:

```
import ActivityA

def test_fizz():
    assert 1 == 1
```

And when I run the tests I get:

```
==>pytest tests/
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.1, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: ***/functions
collected 1 item                                                               

tests/test_foo.py .                                                      [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 0.02s ===============================
```

Comment: I’ll give this a go by creating a separate app. Would a virtual environment make any different to how pytest runs?

Comment: your error isn’t related to a virtual environment but regardless you should be running every program within its own environment

Comment: Just created a new venv and added the modules to the root folder and pytest ran okay. Moved the the module and the tests directory to a sub-directory named function and the pytest failed with the error stated in my question. So the problem is associated with the modules and tests being in the ‘function’ sub-directory.